# Is it possible to set a single default locale for an app?

Tags: android

I'm making an app which supports only 1 language which is RTL, but my device that i debug with locale is en-us, which makes it different from a user in the locale it's meant to be used in.

Is it possible to set a locale for the app so all the users will see the same thing?

I want to do this because i use some libraries that display strings based on the locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your app locale configs using this
If you want to use RTL design and language change Locale instructor parameter to "ar" that means Arabic or "fa" means Farsi or etc.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```